Getting status of 21002 when verifying receipt in IOS react native
I'm trying to implement subscription in react native app on IOS, I've couple of issue first of all I've created two sandbox test users, but upon opening app the prompt doesn't show on first render or when confirming subscriptions in order to put my email and password of sandbox user. Although I'm able to get subscriptions from app store connect though react native iap library, still the verifyReceipt call always return 21002 status.
I've added subscriptions added the In app purchase capability and generated the shared secret. Below is my current implementation
import {
  PurchaseError,
  requestSubscription,
  useIAP,
  validateReceiptIos,
  withIAPContext,
} from 'react-native-iap';
import {IOS_SHARED_SECRET} from '@env';

const SubscriptionModal = ({showSubscribeModal, onCloseModal}) => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

 const {
    connected,
    subscriptions, //returns subscriptions for this app.
    getSubscriptions, //Gets available subsctiptions for this app.
    currentPurchase, //current purchase for the tranasction
    finishTransaction,
    purchaseHistory, //return the purchase history of the user on the device (sandbox user in dev)
    getPurchaseHistory, //gets users purchase history
    getAvailablePurchases,
  } = useIAP();

  useEffect(() => {
    // if (subscriptions) console.log('subscription', subscriptions);
    // if (purchaseHistory) console.log('has purchase history..', purchaseHistory);
    // ... listen if connected, purchaseHistory and subscriptions exist
    if (
      purchase &&
      purchase?.find(
        x => x.productId === (subscriptionSkus[0] || subscriptionSkus[1]),
      )
    ) {
      setAlreadySubscribed(true);
    }
  }, [connected, purchaseHistory, subscriptionSkus, purchase]);

  useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      try {
        const data = await RNIap.getPurchaseHistory();
        setPurchase(data);

        // const receiptBody = {
        //   'receipt-data': data[0]?.transactionReceipt,
        //   password: '*******', // app shared secret, can be found in App Store Connect
        // };
        // console.log(receiptBody);
        // const result = await validateReceiptIos(receiptBody, true);
        // const {status} = result;
        // Alert.alert(JSON.stringify(result));
      } catch (error) {
        console.log('error in validating receipt', error);
      }

      // console.log(new Date(data[0]?.transactionDate));
    })();
  }, [connected, getAvailablePurchases, getPurchaseHistory]);

  const handleFreeTrial = async () => {
    await deviceStorage.saveItem('clickedFreeTrial', true);
    onCloseModal();
  };

  const errorLog = ({message, error}) => {
    console.error('An error happened', message, error);
  };
  // product id from appstoreconnect app->subscriptions
  const subscriptionSkus = Platform.select({
    ios: ['Monthly', 'Yearly'],
  });

  const handleGetSubscriptions = async () => {
    try {
      await getSubscriptions({skus: subscriptionSkus});
    } catch (error) {
      errorLog({message: 'handleGetSubscriptions', error});
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    handleGetSubscriptions();
  }, [connected]);

  const handleBuySubscription = async productId => {
    try {
      const result = await requestSubscription({
        sku: productId,
      });
      console.log('result', result);
      dispatch(setShowSubsciptionModal(true));
      // const data = {
      //   user_id: userProfile.id,
      //   subscription: true,
      //   subscription_plan: selectedOption === 'Monthly' ? 30 : 365,
      //   subscription_price:
      //     selectedOption === 'Monthly'
      //       ? subscriptions[0]?.localizedPrice
      //       : subscriptions[1]?.localizedPrice,
      // };
      // const response = await savePayment(data);
      // dispatch(getUserProfileData(userProfile?.id));
    } catch (error) {
      setLoading(false);
      if (error instanceof PurchaseError) {
        console.log('errorsdasd', error);
        errorLog({message: `[${error.code}]: ${error.message}`, error});
      } else {
        console.log('purchased canceled', error);
        setLoading(false);
        // errorLog({message: 'handleBuySubscription', error});
      }
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const checkCurrentPurchase = async purchase => {
      if (purchase) {
        try {
          const receipt = purchase.transactionReceipt;
          if (receipt) {
            if (Platform.OS === 'ios') {
              const isTestEnvironment = __DEV__;
              //send receipt body to apple server to validete
              const appleReceiptResponse = await validateReceiptIos(
                {
                  'receipt-data': receipt,
                  password: IOS_SHARED_SECRET,
                },
                isTestEnvironment,
              );

              //if receipt is valid
              if (appleReceiptResponse) {
                const {status} = appleReceiptResponse;
                if (status) {
                  // navigation.navigate('Home');
                }
              }
              return;
            }
          }
        } catch (error) {
          console.log('error', error);
        }
      }
    };
    checkCurrentPurchase(currentPurchase);
  }, [currentPurchase, finishTransaction]);

  `


Your receipt is malformed. Make sure it's valid and correctly Base-64 encoded.
P.S. - you probably shouldn't be posting your app shared secret ...

Yeah 21002 status means receipt is malformed but how's that possible I'm getting the receipt whenever I purchase and passing that same receipt along with the password, but still getting the same response

Is there anything i am missing in my storekit file

The receipt is not something you get when you purchase - it's something you get off the device.

actually i want when user purchased a plan, I want to verify the transaction receipt like if it's subscription is still active, when it's going to expire etc?

for that purpose I'm trying to hit verifyReceiptIos api call, and in the response it has all that data, but somehow it returns me status of 21002, I've passed the correct base64 encoded string although my encoded string doesn't end with "==" but still I searched on google and it's valid

Try to check the receipt validation in sandbox environment rather than storkit.

Create the sandbox tester account on the Apple account

Add that sandbox account on your IOS device :: settings -> App store -> Add sanbox tester account

disable the storekit configuration on the xcode , go to product - > scheme -> Edit scheme -> Run(on left side) -> in Option Tab set storkitConfiguration to "None"


(Make sure for in-App purchases your App should have signed App agreement, then only you can fetch products in sanbox and Production environment)
Docs for your reference
Paid Agreement for in-App purchases
https://developer.apple.com/help/app-store-connect/manage-agreements/sign-and-update-agreements/
sandbox Testing
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/testing-in-app-purchases-with-sandbox
